# Memoize implementation using eval. Is this use of eval acceptable?

Tags: javascript, eval, memoization

...or are there better ways to implement a Memoization?

```js
Function.memoize = function(callableAsString)
    {
    var r = false, callable, code;
    try
        {
        callable = eval(callableAsString);
        if (typeof callable == "function" && typeof(Function.memoize.cache[callableAsString]) == "undefined")
            {
            code = callableAsString + " = function()" + 
                "{" +
                "var cache = Function.memoize.cache['" + callableAsString + "'];" +
                "var k = Json.stringify([this].concat(arguments));" +
                "return cache.r[k] || (cache.r[k] = cache.c.apply(this, arguments));" +
                "};" +
                "true;";
            if (r = eval(code))
                {
                Function.memoize.cache[callableAsString] = {c: callable, r: {}};
                }
            }
        }
    catch (e) {}
    return r;
    };
Function.memoize.cache = {};
Function.memoize("String.prototype.camelize");
```

**Update based on the suggestions by Felix Kling**

```
Function.memoize = function(callable)
    {
    var r = false;
    if (typeof callable == "function")
        {
        var hash = callable.toString().hashCode();
        r = function()
            {
            var cache = Function.memoize.cache[hash];
            var key = Json.stringify([this].concat(arguments));
            return cache.r[key] || (cache.r[key] = cache.c.apply(this, arguments));
            }
        if (!Function.memoize.cache)
            {
            Function.memoize.cache = {};
            }
        r.memoize = callable;
        Function.memoize.cache[hash] = {c: callable, r: {}};
        }
    return r;
    };

Function.unmemoize = function(callable)
    {
    if (callable.memoize && typeof callable.memoize == "function")
        {
        return callable.memoize;
        }
    else
        {
        return false;
        }
    };

String.prototype.camelize = Function.memoize(String.prototype.camelize);
String.prototype.camelize = Function.unmemoize(String.prototype.camelize);
```

Comment: I don't see any advantage over just passing a function reference. Also note that `JSON.stringify` fails if you have objects with circular references.

Comment: Thanks for you input. FYI: I'm using a wrapper for JSON.stringify that uses the [replacer](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_native_JSON#The_replacer_parameter) parameter to handle circular references and the "serialisation" of DOM object. This is required as the arguments array can also contain objects with circular references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see the need for eval... consider this implementation

```
function memoize(f, cache)
{
    if (!cache) cache = {};
    return function()
    {
        var key = JSON.stringify(arguments);
        return (cache[key] || (cache[key] = [f.apply(this, arguments)]))[0];
    }
}
```

Note that I deliberately ignored `this` in the key. The reason is that `this` may not be serializable by `stringify` (e.g. because of loops) and this is more the rule than the exception for example when `this == window` i.e. in the global context.

What is IMO useful is the ability to explictly pass the cache, so that you can for example create a separate cache for each instance or one shared cache for all instances by doing something like:

```
function MyObj(...)
{
    // every instance has its own cache
    this.foo = memoize(function(...) { ... });

    // there is one shared cache for all instances
    this.bar = memoize(function(...) { ... }, MyObj.memoize_cache);
}

MyObj.memoize_cache = {};
```

Comment: TBH i'm not satiesfied with your solution because i want object definition and memoization to be separated. The reason i used eval was for seperation and this requires a unique key for the function; `callableAsString` was that key. You may want to check out the updated version using Function.toString().hashCode() (implementation of [java.lang.String.hashCode()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#hashCode%28%29)) as unique key for the function.

You suggestion showed me the way to get rid of eval. Thanks.