# How underscore memoize is implemented in javascript

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, memoization

I'm developing my own functional-programming library, and now referring the `underscore`.

[**memoize**   _.memoize(function, [hashFunction])](http://underscorejs.org/#memoize)

> Memoizes a given function by caching the computed result. Useful for speeding up slow-running computations. If passed an optional hashFunction, it will be used to compute the hash key for storing the result, based on the arguments to the original function. The default hashFunction just uses the first argument to the memoized function as the key.

```
var fibonacci = _.memoize(function(n) {
  return n < 2 ? n: fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);
});
```

The above code that enables automatic memorisation without dealing `array` looks sort of magic, and I saw the source-code below, but still the inner design is not clear to me.

```
 // Memoize an expensive function by storing its results.
  _.memoize = function(func, hasher) {
    var memoize = function(key) {
      var cache = memoize.cache;
      var address = hasher ? hasher.apply(this, arguments) : key;
      if (!_.has(cache, address)) cache[address] = func.apply(this, arguments);
      return cache[key];
    };
    memoize.cache = {};
    return memoize;
  };
```

Can someone give me a brief idea of what is going on?

Appreciated.

Comment: What parts of it don't you understand or are struggling with?

Comment: Why aren't you looking at the most recent version of Underscore? That's not the current implementation of `_.memoize`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`memoize` has a `cache` (`memoize.cache = {}`) that uses for storing the result of the function call. When it's called, it determines an `address` to store the result by two means: either a call to the `hasher` function, or the `key` parameter.

The hasher function works like this (from the underscore page):

> If passed an optional hashFunction, it will be used to compute the
>   hash key for storing the result, based on the arguments to the
>   original function. The default hashFunction just uses the first
>   argument to the memoized function as the key.

Then, it calls the function you passed `func.apply(...)`, and stores the result at `cache[address]`.

The second time you call the memoized function, the result will already be in cache (`!_.has(..)` will return `false`) and the computation won't be repeated.

I dont' understand why it returns `cache[key]` and not `cache[address]` tough...seems to me that `cache[address]` would be the correct choice.

### Update

As pointed out in the comments, the code you present is not the latest implementation of `memoize`. This is the latest implementation (1.6.0):

```
_.memoize = function(func, hasher) {
    var memo = {};
    hasher || (hasher = _.identity);
    return function() {
      var key = hasher.apply(this, arguments);
      return _.has(memo, key) ? memo[key] : (memo[key] = func.apply(this, arguments));
    };
  };
```

It works the same way, except from the fact that it is a little more elegant; if an `hasher` function it's not provided, it uses `_.identity` as a key, that is a function that simply returns the value passed as an argument:

```
_.identity = function(value) { return value; }
```

Aside from this, `cache` is now called `memo` but works the same way.

Comment: Thanks link. Is this identical solution to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7497914/memoize-implementation-using-eval-is-this-use-of-eval-acceptable?rq=1 ?

Comment: Yes, the idea is very similar. The solution from that question includes also a check for the type of the argument passed to `memoize` (it makes sure it is a function), and a different method of computing the address for the cache (it takes `callable.toString().hashCode()`).

Comment: It using `_.identity` is not elegant at all; `_.identity` is unary.

Comment: I can't get the point that when the cache is created it is localized to the function and should not be available to the outer scope then how it is a cache to the script? How it caches function and recalls afterward if called later called with the same argument?

Comment: @Saqlain `memoize` returns a closure, so it keeps a reference to the outer `memo`, which will be the same for every invocation.

Answer (score 0):

```
const memorized = (fn) => {
  let cache = {}
  const makeKey = (...args) => {
    return args.map((o) => JSON.stringify(o)).join('_')
  }

  return function (...args) {
    const key = makeKey(args)

    if (cache[key]) {     
      console.log('return from cache')   
      return cache[key]
    } else {
      console.log('calculating')
      const newValue = fn(...args)
      cache[key] = newValue
      return newValue
    }
  }
}
const sum = (a, b, c)=> a + b + c
const square = a => a*a
const sumMemorized = memorized(sum)
const squareMemorized = memorized(square)
sumMemorized(1,2,3)
sumMemorized(1,2,3)
sumMemorized(1,2,3)
sumMemorized(1,2,3)
sumMemorized(1,2,3)
squareMemorized(2)
squareMemorized(3)
```