# Currying event handlers in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, functional-programming, currying

I am trying to write a (curried?) `onChange` event handler on a Component that will receive a `key` argument which will let it know which key in the state object to update. The code won't compile, saying `'key' is not defined`.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      firstName: null,
      lastName: null
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange = (key) = (event) => {
    console.log(key, event);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>

        <form>
          <input onChange={this.handleChange('firstName')} value={this.state.firstName} />
          <input onChange={this.handleChange('lastName')} value={this.state.firstName} />
        </form>

        {JSON.stringify(this.state, null, 4)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: handleChange = (key) => (event) =>

Comment: why you are making it so complex, use this: `onChange={(e) => this.handleChange('firstName', e)}` then use `handleChange` like this: `handleChange(key, e){console.log(key, e)}`

Comment: @madox2 Thanks! I can't believe I missed that.

Comment: @MayankShukla Because using a callback there means that a function is created every re-render, which means more work for the garbage collector (or so I am told). Also I wanted to learn about currying!

Comment: You won't be saving memory with this, unless you then [`memoize`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30386943/how-to-create-a-memoize-function) the returned functions per their key :). Inline functions pose a different problem... they cause PureComponent checks to fail as every reference is different.

Comment: And sorry to be a Killjoy but this aint no [currying](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36314/what-is-currying) too :p, you have created a function factory, which is fun nonetheless!

Comment: @hazardous: I'm curoious - where do you draw the line between a function factory and currying? The code written by the OP seems pretty much identical to the accepted answer on the "what is currying" question you linked (minus the arrow functions).

Comment: Simple, currying is taking a function with several params and wrapping it in a way to allow only one param at a time. If a function only takes one param, that's not currying. The linked example (now I realize), stops short on defining the curry translation function which takes the multiparam function and returns a curried version.

Comment: From https://wiki.haskell.org/Currying: "Currying is the process of transforming a function that takes multiple arguments into a function that takes just a single argument and returns another function if any arguments are still needed." OP had a function that took two arguments, "key" and "event", and decided to transform that to a function that takes one argument, "key", and returns a function because more arguments are still needed. That's currying.

Comment: The event handler is already a series of functions taking one argument each. An important part of currying is this - `f(a,b) = f(a)(b)`. The first form is absent. Anyways, I was nudging the OP towards exploring the translator mechanisms in JS to curry a multi-param function. @NoobOfNoobs: please check this out: https://medium.com/@kevincennis/currying-in-javascript-c66080543528!

Answer (score 3):

You have to pass both the `event` as well as the `key` on the `OnChange` handler.

Do this

```
<input onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this,'firstName')} value={this.state.firstName} />
```

And the `onChange` should be

```
 handleChange = (key, event) => {
    console.log(key, event);
  }
```

This will allow both the `event` and `key` to be passed and the function will work.

Comment: Your solution *does* create a new function per render. That's exactly what [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) does.

Answer (score 2):

I think that in your code you have just forgotten to put the arrow function after initializing first function name:

```
handleChange = (key) = [!!! HERE - should be an arrow !!!] (event) => {
  console.log(key, event);
}
```

Try to use this:

```
handleChange = (key) => (event) => {
  console.log(key, event);
}
```

So this way your first function which has the param `key` will return another function with param `event`.