# How to store arguments between function calls in JS

Tags: javascript, function

A function is getting called multiple times is there a way to store the context/arguments of last function call and check with current ones.

Comment: You can check the implementation of this https://github.com/getify/TNG-Hooks#usecallback-hook

Comment: Related: [How to create a memoize function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30386943/218196)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When defining the function, I'd use a closure to store a persistent variable, reassigned to the arguments passed on every call, eg:

```js
const fn = (() => {
  let lastArgs;
  return (...args) => {
    console.log('function was called with args:', args);
    console.log('past args were:', lastArgs);
    lastArgs = args;
  };
})();

fn('foo', 'bar');
fn('baz');
```

Comment: That is awesome

Comment: There was an interesting challenge about this in codewars, as far as I can remember.

Comment: are there more ways to accomplish this, I would like your feedback ?

Comment: @KunalMukherjee I'm not sure whether there is a cleaner way than this one. It's clear and flexible enough, not sure whether its worth to look for another solution :P

Comment: @KunalMukherjee You can also assign to an outside variable, but that means that the `lastArgs` loses its closure privacy. Another option is to assign to a property of the function, eg `function foo(...args) { foo.lastArgs = args }`, but functions *shouldn't* have non-standard properties like that. IMO the closure solution is the best by far, the others aren't worth thinking about. Another *odd* solution would be to reassign the function every time you call it, I guess

Comment: @CertainPerformance works fine in console, not in my project. the args is undefined so lastarg is always set to undefined

Comment: @amitavamozumder It sounds like you're using code different from the code in the answer - argument rest syntax will *never* be `undefined` (at worst, it'll be an empty array), can you show a [MCVE]?

Comment: @CertainPerformance yes, pastargs is redefining every time and getting undefined ...args is empty array.

Comment: self invocation issue with my framework. It's working now.

Comment: @CertainPerformance losing context of this inside return, saving it as another var after lastArg doesn't hep either. any idea why ?

Comment: @amitavamozumder Hard to say without seeing the code. Keep in mind that arrow functions inherit their `this` from the surrounding scope, not from the calling context

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196907/discussion-between-amitava-mozumder-and-certainperformance).

Comment: One bad thing about this though, is that this function does nothing. Would be cool to see this working with a real function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a global variable for storing data. Everytime a new function called check new arguments with global variable and do what you want.

Comment: this is an anti-pattern. We shouldn't clutter global space.

Comment: Yes you are right , I just wanted to help. Comment above is true way to do it.