# Javascript Memoization Implementation

Tags: javascript, memoization

I've been debating this topic with my mates at work.
I would like to know from you guys, if this is, actually, the right way of implementing the memoization.

```js
function memoize(result) {
  let cache = {};

  return function() {
    if (cache[result]) {
      // returns cached result / no calculation
      return cache[result];
    }
    // calculating...
    cache[result] = result;
    return cache[result];
  };
}

function expensiveCalculation() {
  let counter = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
    counter += i;
  }
  return counter;
}

console.time("FirstCalculation");
const memoizedExpensiveCalculation = memoize(expensiveCalculation());
console.timeEnd("FirstCalculation");

console.time("1_Memoized");
memoizedExpensiveCalculation();
console.timeEnd("1_Memoized");

console.time("2_Memoized");
memoizedExpensiveCalculation();
console.timeEnd("2_Memoized");

console.time("3_Memoized");
memoizedExpensiveCalculation();
console.timeEnd("3_Memoized");
```

The time logs reveals, in fact, the first time takes much more time (which we would expect) and less time afterwards.

Comment: it's not right. you don't even call the function.

Comment: Your code makes no sense your result is the key and what you return?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a memoize function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30386943/how-to-create-a-memoize-function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like:

```
function get(func) {
  let cache = {};

  return function(key) {
    if (key in cache) {
      return cache[key];
    }
    cache[key] = func(key);
    return cache[key];
 };
}

function expensiveCalculation(param) {
  console.log('expensive calculation runs')
  let counter = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    counter += i;
  }
  return param*2;
}
const memo = get(expensiveCalculation)
console.log('start')
console.log('first try');
console.log(memo(10));
console.log('second try');
console.log(memo(10));
```

Comment: This is actually very useful. You grabbed my implementation and filled in what's missing. Thank you!

Comment: with pleasure ! will be glad if you accept this answer :)

Answer (score 1):

it's not correct

---

The code you shows

```js
function memoize(result) {
  let cache = {};

  return function() {
    if (cache[result]) {
      // returns cached result / no calculation
      return cache[result];
    }
    // calculating...
    cache[result] = result;
    return cache[result];
  };
}
```

is basically

```
function memoize(result) {
  return result
}
```

---

in  memoization what you cache is **input/output pair** and skip real function call when **input** match.

Comment: What should be changed?

Comment: @JGS well it's completely wrong. You need to rewrite whole thing. I've update the answer a little.

Comment: Could you give me a code snippet as an example?

Comment: @JGS https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30386943/how-to-create-a-memoize-function is an example.

Comment: I was expecting that you could fill in the missing parts but rather you told me "rewrite the whole thing". That was quite brutal and toxic :P But thanks anyway!